# Default value of DateTimeField for South migration in Django project with activated timezone support

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-timezone

I'm creating a schema migration with South 0.7.6 for my Django 1.4.3 project with enabled timezone support.

The schema migration includes adding a `DateTimeField` (with `auto_now=True`) on one table.

When creating the migration, South prompts me:

```
The field 'MyTable.my_field' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
```

What's the correct one-off value to give here, if I don't care about this value for existing rows (I just want the migration to succeed without warnings)?

So far, I used `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`. However, then I get the following when applying the migration:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:808:
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-01-16 00:00:00)
while time zone support is active.
```

South does not seem to import pytz or the Django helper classes, so how can I give a timezone-aware default value here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manually edit the migration file that South created and add:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

Then find the field that you are adding in the migration file and set its `default` to `timezone.now()`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! Not a big fan of having to edit my South migration files by hand everytime I'm working with a `DateTimeField` however. Is this the current best practice?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure. Obviously you _must_ provide a timezone aware default value somehow... Maybe a bigger guru than I can comment on any other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

pytz can be used for making timezone-aware datetime objects. you can use the following in your migration file:

```
import pytz
cn_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
```

then in your model

```
self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(auto_now=True, default=datetime.datetime.now(cn_tz), blank=True),
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when I ran migrations on dev machine, it was different than when I ran them on production.

My dev machine at the top of the file has

```
    from south_utils import datetime_utils as datetime
```

where on production it generated

```
    import datetime
```

By replacing the latter with the former, it solved my issue with no additional edits to the migration file.