# Django: Change TimeField to DateTimeField in models.py

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

In my models.py, i have some models with this kind of attributes:

```
timestamp = models.TimeField(default=0)
```

I want to change them to:

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=0)
```

Using

```
python manage.py schemamigration app --auto
```

works in first instance. 
But

```
python manage.py migrate app
```

leads to this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "timestamp" cannot be cast to type timestamp with time zone
```

So i somehow needs to make this casting possible. For every time without date i want to set a default date (e.g. yesterday). How can i do this? 
I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027444/changing-datefield-to-datetimefield-in-django) on SO, which does not help at all because of that error. 
BTW: I am using postgres and python3.

I appreciate your help!

It is okay for me to use SQL direct on the database (without south) if that's easier

Comment: the thing you probably want is called Data Migration: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations

Comment: Would this post help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14362743/1628832

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because `time` cannot be converted (casted) to `timestamp` (neither their time-zone related variants) in PostgreSQL. F.ex. this will also fail:

```
SELECT 'now'::time::timestamp
```

In these cases, you should use the `USING` clause in your `ALTER TABLE` statement (if you can edit it directly):

```
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] [ ONLY ] name [ * ]
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name
[ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ USING expression ]
```

Your query will look like, f.ex.:

```
ALTER TABLE "my_model"
ALTER COLUMN "column_name"
SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE USING 'yesterday'::date + "column_name"
```

Comment: "That's because time cannot be converted (casted) to timestamp (neither their time-zone related variants) in PostgreSQL."

Aughhhhh. Then how did the shitty schema I'm working with right now pass code revieeewwwwww.

Thanks this answer was really helpful.

Comment: did the above steps but still getting the same error

Answer (score 5):

If you didn't have any data in your tables, then you can delete your migrations from migrations folder of your app and change the field to DateTime then do the initial migration.
My problem solved,  without touching the SQL Queries